# Tiempo de vida de un objeto

Tags: java, poo, contador

Necesito hacer un programa con java que cada 30 segundos cree un objeto y lo meta en una cola y luego ya haga unas operaciones con ellos. Había pensado en crear el objeto y que al crearlo se creara también una especie de contador, de forma que cuando llegue a 30 segundos, se cree otro objeto hasta que tengas 100.

He intentado algo con System.currentTimeMillis(); pero no se me ocurre como hacer que cuente 30 segundos y entonces haga otras operaciones.

He estado buscando y he intentado esto:

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                do {
                Camion c = new Camion();
                A.add(c);
                System.out.println(c.toString());
                }while(A.size()<100);
            }
        };

        timer.schedule(task, 30000);
```

Pero no es lo que quería, esto lo hace de golpe a los 30 segundos.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Varias cosas, esto se puede hacer, en cualquier lenguaje, pero si no especificas el lenguaje nadie va a poder contestarte. Debes intentar hacer algo, y mostrar un progreso respecto a eso, y despues podemos ayudarte con los problemas que encuentres.

Comment: ¿Has mirado [`ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleWithFixedDelay()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleWithFixedDelay(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit))? También tienes [`ScheduledExecutorService.scheduleAtFixedRate()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#scheduleAtFixedRate(java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit)).

Comment: Agrega lo que has investigado o intentado, revisa [ask], saludos!

Comment: El Timer parece que es lo que estás buscando, le indicas el tiempo que deseas y lo que quieres que haga y a funcionar. http://www.chuidiang.org/java/timer/timer.php

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano desgraciadamente `Timer` es sensible a cambios en el reloj del sistema, usa un solo hilo de ejecución y cualquier `RuntimeException` es capaz de parar ese hilo. `ExecutorService` es una solución más moderna con ninguno de estos problemas y diría que la mejor opción para este caso

Comment: No veo porque Timer se va a ir cambiando si haces un cambio en el reloj. A ese timer le indicas lo que quires que haga cada x milisegundos, no vas comparando con la hora del reloj (no es que no esté de acuerdo con lo que dices, simplemente no veo que le pueda afectar).

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano [La descripción del método `schedule()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#schedule-java.util.TimerTask-java.util.Date-long-) lo explica un poco: `Timer` usa `Object.wait()`, `Object.wait()` depende de `System.currentTimeMillis()`, y `System.currentTimeMillis()` depende del reloj del sistema, que puede ser inconsistente en ciertos casos. La descripción de la clase `Timer` en sí indica que los contenidos de `java.util.concurrent` se pueden usar como reemplazo directo sin problema y detalla las ventajas.

Answer (score 0):

Se me ocurre una manera de hacer esto con clases `static`.

Como menciona @OscarGarcia, la manera estándar de lograr delays fijos es con un [`ScheduledExecutorService`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html):

```
private static ScheduledExecutorService servicio = new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1);
```

Además de esto, si quieres cancelar el programa tras 100 intentos necesitarás un [`ScheduledFuture`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledFuture.html):

```
private static ScheduledFuture<?> futuro;
```

Una vez tienes esto, es tan simple como definir una variable extra en tu `Runnable` que mantenga un contador de veces que se ha ejecutado:

```
private static class CrearCamion implements Runnable {

    private int ejecuciones = 1;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        if(++ejecuciones > 100) {
            futuro.cancel(false); // cancelamos si llevamos más de 100
        } else {
            Camion c = new Camion();
            A.add(c);
            System.out.println(c.toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Y por último, en tu `main()`, asegúrate de asignar el `ScheduledFuture` al resultado de la llamada a `scheduleAtFixedRate`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    // el tercer y el cuarto argumento determinan el tiempo de espera entre ejecuciones
    futuro = servicio.scheduleAtFixedRate(new CrearCamion(), 0, 30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}
```

Pruébalo :)